# Handling circular dependency in Angular 4+

Tags: angular

I have multiple providers which depends on each other (actually there are HTTP Interceptor and 2 providers). In interceptor I handled circular dependency via Injector:

```
this.injector.get(AuthProvider).authToken
```

This trick doesn't worked with providers. I have AuthProvider and RestaurantProvider. If I spread methods where shall be than it looks like:

```js
export class RestaurantProvider {
  ....................
  auth(email: string, password: string): Observable<{ token: string }> {
    return this.http
      .post<responseFormat>(environment.api + "/restaurant/auth", {
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      .map((res: responseFormat) => res.data as { token: string });
  }
  ....................
  restaurantImageAdd(image: string): Promise<FileUploadResult> {
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: "images",
      chunkedMode: false
      //params: {}  //body params
    };

    let token = this.authProvider.authToken;
    if (token) {
      options.headers = {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
      };
    }

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    return fileTransfer.upload(
      image,
      environment.api + "/restaurant/images",
      options
    );
  }
  ....................
}

export class AuthProvider {
  login(email: string, password: string): Promise<boolean | string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.restaurantProvider.auth(email, password).subscribe(
        res => {
          if (res.hasOwnProperty("token")) {
            this.setAuthToken(res.token).then(() => {
              this.events.publish("login");
              resolve(true);
            });
          }
        },
        err => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

And :

As you see RestaurantProvider use AuthProvider depends on each other. Thus it cause circular dependency... Injector doesn't handle this (don't know why). I aimed to use [SkipSelf](https://angular.io/api/core/SkipSelf) or [forwardRef](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef) but none of them caused any positive result. Probably I used it wrong or I can't use them in this case... Currently the only workaround I found is to move auth method from RestaurantProvider into AuthProvider .

Anyway I just want to ask how you guys are handling circular dependency? Any ideas are welcomed

Comment: Maybe use a third service just for storing and handling of the token?

Comment: Practically I use HttpInterceptor ( https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) for headers amendments - authentications. But the point is that Injector use properly for it.. Although I don't really like it... Wanna find some other solutions. The point is that there are always some areas where you face this problem, I just want to know how to properly handle these cases properly, without finding workarounds all the time.

Comment: Well, I have a TokenService (which just stores the auth token) in my app.module and my auth interceptor is in a sub module which is used after logging in. I don't need the injector there, because the TokenService can be passed in the interceptors constructor. And in my AuthService I also use that TokenService to store the token returned from the server when logging in.

Comment: Injector is nice way to handle authentication and process errors. It just 100 lines of code which handle all request and authentication for everything. Regarding this part "because the TokenService can be passed in the interceptors constructor" TokenService the most certainly use HttpClient. Therefore if you pass it into interceptors constructor it will cause dependency error...

Answer (score 0):

As @Fussel mentioned in comments, you can use the third service, or exclude one of the services from another one (for example `AuthProvider`), and just pass all necessary data to this service from component, like this:

**RestaurantProvider**

```
// add 'token' as one of parameters
restaurantImageAdd(image: string, token: any): Promise<FileUploadResult> {
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: "images",
      chunkedMode: false
      //params: {}  //body params
    };

    if (token) {
      options.headers = {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
      };
    }

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    return fileTransfer.upload(
      image,
      environment.api + "/restaurant/images",
      options
    );
  }
```

**AnyComponent**

```
...
export class AnyComponent {
  ...
  constructor(private _authProvider: AuthProvider,
              private _restaurantProvider: RestaurantProvider) {
    _restaurantProvider.restaurantImageAdd('imageUrl', _authProvider.authToken) // pass 'token' as the second parameter
  }
}
```

Comment: In that case you are just moving the logic our of the service - radically extending component code.... In other words you can always find some solutions which will work, but if there are methods such as SkipSelf or forwardRef in Angular core, propably there is a better solution to handle it.  As I was replying to @Fussel. I use Interceptor... token itself is irrelevant to the question. There is no way you can move anything out of it (AuthService also use HttpClient)

Comment: @Timothy, *"In that case you are just moving the logic our of the service - radically extending component code"*. Yes, because components are for business logic, don't keep it in services.

Answer (score 0):

To add some code to this.

TokenService does not require HttpClient, it's not more than this.

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenService {
    auth_token_key: string = "auth_token";

    constructor() {
    }

    get token(): string {
        return localStorage.getItem(this.auth_token_key);
    }

    set token(token: string) {
        localStorage.setItem(this.auth_token_key, token);
    }
}
```

A simplified interceptor could look like this.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if(this.tokenService.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.tokenService.token}`
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

And the AuthService somewhat like this

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl+'/auth';

    private headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private tokenService: TokenService) {}

    login(user: String, password: String): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/login`, JSON.stringify({'login': user, 'password': password}), {headers: this.headers}).toPromise().then((t: Token) => {
            this.tokenService.token = t.token;
            return true;
        });
    }
```

As I said the AuthInterceptor in my case is used in sub modules while the TokenService is provided by the app.module but this works without circular dependency errors and to me atleast this seems like a clean solution without using the injector.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Appreciate it. But its not applyable to my situation.